# How to use Vpython (visual) from an IDE

Tags: python, vpython, spyder

I'm very new to python and I don't entirely understand versions and libraries, so there may be a simple solution to my problem.

I am working on a project in which it is vital that we visually display our simulation. I installed Vpython on Mac OSX 10.8.4 and so far visualizations work when running the program from the command line. However I'd like to use an IDE (Eclipse, Sublime Text, Spyder. Ideally Spyder) but whenever `from visual import *` shows up, I get the following error:

```
  >>> runfile(r'/Users/robinnewhouse/code/Spyder/astro/maintest.py', wdir=r'/Users/robinnewhouse/code/Spyder/astro')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 523, in     runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/robinnewhouse/code/Spyder/astro/maintest.py", line 7, in <module>
    from visual import *
ImportError: No module named visual
```

So I tried using Spyder's PYTHONPATH manager to add the path to the package. I got the same error.

Then in a last ditch effort, I tried to manually add the "visual" package to Spyder's directory of included packages (/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/) and I got a different (albeit worse) error: `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread`

I have no idea how to deal with this issue, but the most frustrating part is that if I run the same file in command line, it works fine. (speaking of which, if it helps, the version of python that comes up when I use `which python` is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Spyder dev here) The right solution is this: In *Spyder* you need to go

`Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python Executable`

and then change the file that appears there to be

`/usr/bin/python`

However, before doing this you need to reinstall *Spyder* again, because you added the `visual` module to it and now it's broken.

Comment: As a side note, I have to admit that it's not easy at all for our users to figure it out how to use modules that don't come with our app. But we are working hard to improve the situation in our next version (2.3).

Comment: AH! It works! Thanks a lot Carlos.
Just in case anyone else is looking at this, I had to change the python executable to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` which seems to be the path that Vpython demands I use. /usr/bin/python wouldn't even run Vpython in command line

Comment: Ok Robin, thanks for the clarification. It seems you have your own Python installation (different from the Apple's one) and that's why you need to pass a different path to the option I mentioned. But that's totally fine :)